# Android: Seeing The null function in "name of app" has been disabled. To enable it, go to Settings

Tags: android, permissions

Any idea what this means? I have a guess that it happens when the phone upgrades from Android version M to L, which has all the new fine grained permission settings. Google said that the upgrade should be backwards compatible, but I'm wondering if there are edge cases that could cause an error like this. And if so, how I can go about fixing it.

Comment: One of my clients has the same problem on a 5.1.1 device. Did you find any useful info about this problem?